# Codes that can solve $f'[a x]$

Tags: differential-equations, syntax, packages

The usual Dsolve and NDSolve command are unable to sovle ODEs like

```
pfun = NDSolveValue[{1/2 *g'[InverseFunction[g][f[x]]] - x + f[x] == 0,f '[InverseFunction[f][g[1/2*x]]] - 1/2 *x + g[1/2*x] == 0, f[0] == 0, g[0] == 0, h[0] == 0},{f, g}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

And I believe the problem lies in expressions $f[a x]$, especially for the non-standard argument $ax$.  Dsolve and NDSolve may only recognize $f[x]$ instead.

So I am wondering are there any packages or other commands/codes that can solve ODEs with such type of argument?

Comment: Are you aware of any software *outside* of Mathematica that solves such problems? When an ODE contains both `f[x]` and `f[x - a]` for a constant `a`, it's called a delay diff. eq. I haven't seen any for this kind in which one has both `f[x]` and `f[a x]`. Can one transform `f'[x] == F[f[x], f[a x]]` to `E^-y g'[y] == F[g[y], g[y-b]]` where `g[Log[t]] == f[t]`, `x == Exp[y]` and `a == Exp[-b]`?

Comment: Actually another problem seems to be `g'[InverseFunction[g][f[x]]]`...which looks quite different.....

Comment: Do you have a reference for this sort of problem?

Comment: This is the problem I encounter in my own work. And I am aware of the delayed differential equations, but I am not sure this system can be defined as delayed diff eq since it is $ax$ instead of $x-a$.

Comment: I think one could transform a "scaling delay" $ax$ to a "translation delay" $y-b$ as I indicated above. I don't know any software that handles variable delays such as occur in `g'[InverseFunction[g][f[x]]]`, in which `f` problem has to be solved at `x` and `InverseFunction[g]` has to be solved at `f[x]` in order to advance the solution of `g` at `InverseFunction[g][f[x]]`. It's probably not a common type of problem, which means most common software packages probably do not solve it. You might get lucky and find some, or you might have to write your own, if such an algorithm can be invented.

Comment: Actually, the     g'[InverseFunction[g][f[x]]] thing   can be solved when $a=1$, but it is not solvable when $a$ is any other constant.